# Input multiple integers from user and output to text file C++

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I have to get multiple integers (temperatures) from the user and then output to a text file; I just completed a similar assignment however, the input was from a file and it was a little bit more straight forward. I am tempted to just create 12 integers say temp1-temp12, but I feel like there has got to be a more efficient way. I am about  weeks into my first C++ college level class if that matters. Here's an excerpt from the assignment.

> Write an interactive C++ program whose input is a serious of 12 temperatures from the user. It should write out on file tempdata.txt each temperature as well as the difference between the current temperature and the one preceding it. The difference is not output for the first temperature that is input. At the end of the program, the average temperature should be displayed for the user via cout. For example, given the input data
>   34.5  38.6  42.4  46.8  51.3  63.1  60.2  55.9  60.3  56.7  50.3  42.4

Thanks Guys!

Comment: any attempts by yourself??

Comment: hint: arrays and cin! also show us what you tried..

Comment: hint 2: take arrays and loops and mix them together

Comment: You should read up on [`cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/), [`for`-loops](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/), and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Have you gotten it to work the way you were "tempted" to do it? You can do it with an array, or you can get by with three integers.

Comment: I apologize if I broke any rules, I'll try to search harder next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Query: Write an interactive C++ program whose input is a serious of 12 temperatures from the user. It should write out on file tempdata.txt each temperature as well as the difference between the current temperature and the one preceding it. The difference is not output for the first temperature that is input. At the end of the program, the average temperature should be displayed for the user via cout. For example, given the input data 34.5 38.6 42.4 46.8 51.3 63.1 60.2 55.9 60.3 56.7 50.3 42.4

**HINT**

Some of the elements of your program should include

`fstream` elements i.e. `ofstream filename`, which is used for `filename.open("filename.txt")`. 
`iostream` elements i.e. `cin, cout` which will take in input from the console and output to the console.
a while loop that will read in elements 12 times i.e.

```
ofstream tempdata // this outputs to the file
type counter = 0; //WHAT TYPE SHOULD THIS BE?
type previoustemp //??? what type? how can I use this in the while loop below?
double temperature;
while(counter < 12){
cin >> temperature;
tempdata << previoustemp - temperature; //previoustemp is undefined here. How can I define it?
}
cout << avgtemp //not only undefined, but undeclared. This should sum up all twelve elements and divide by 12 to get the average. An array is not needed.
```

This is an incomplete example but it should get you started.

Comment: OK thank you that definitely got me going!